# vector direction for vertical or horizontal line segments

Tags: vectors

I have start and end vertices of vertical and horizontal line segments. How do I calculate their corresponding direction for the line segments based on their start and end points?

Comment: You subtract the values of start from end point and multiply by the unit vector for the certain axis. Example: $(x_2-x_1)i$ for the x component of the vector.

Comment: what did you exactly mean by "unit vector for the certain axis" ? Did you mean to multiply by the x-component of the unit vector. Then how to calculate the unit vector in the first place ?

Comment: The unit vector is given as a unit in the direction of the axis, typically I for x.

Comment: I am doing it as follows(probably it is a overdo): 1. get the vector value by substracing the start point from the end point. 2. Get the length of the vector. 3. Divide the x-component of the vector by the length. 4. Check if the value is greater than 0, if it is , then the horizontal line is proceeding towards the positive x-direction, otherwise it is going towards the negative x-direction.

Answer (score 0):

$(x_2-x_1)i+(y_2-y_1)j+(z_2-z_1)k$ is the vector in 3D  - going from P1 to P2